# Hide file in doxygen file list, but need to parse it

Tags: c, doxygen

I have some .h files and some .c files, I need those .c files for generating the function call graph, but I don't want the .c files to appear in the file list. If I add .c files to EXCLUDE, then I can't get the function call graph. That means doxygen is not parsing my .c file, which is not what I want.

Is there any way to make doxygen parse .c files but not include it to the file list?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? DOd you have `SOURCE_BROWSER` enabled? If so what happens when you disable it?

Comment: 1.9.5. Maybe something wrong with my expression. I want to keep .h files in the files list, but I want .c files to be parsed and hidden in the files list. After disabling SOURCE_BROWSER, the files list did not change.

Comment: The, code,  parsing of the files containing the call / caller information (i.e. the code of the function) is necessary to obtain the call / caller graphs. (In the past it was necessary to set the `SOURCE_BROWSER=YES` but this restriction has been lifted.) The situation you give now is that you want to have the the call / caller graphs that is hidden in the (here) .c files but don't want to see the .c files. I don;t think this is possible at the moment.